# How to run a python script with a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, program-entry-point

I have a python file named `main.py` which looks like this:

```
print('hello world')
```

I also have a `tkinkter_run.py` file which looks like this:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
import main

window=Tk()

window.title("Running Python Script")
window.geometry('550x200')

def run():
    os.system('main.py')

btn = Button(window, text="Run your Code!", bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

When I run my `tkinker_run.py` file I do get a window with a `Run your Code!` button, however when I click that button and look the my terminal in Visual Code I get the following error:

```
Hello World
'main.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So it seems that `Hello World` is printed before I even click the `Run your Code!` button. I dont understand what the problem is....

Comment: @martineau What do you mean?

Comment: Is `main.py` in the same directory as `tkinkter_run.py`?

Comment: @AST Yes it is.

Comment: @TangerCity Also, `Hello World` is initially printed because you have called `import main`. Try using `os.system(os.path.abspath('main.py'))`, just to make sure that the correct path is supplied.

Comment: @AST I get this when I click that `run the Code!` button `C:\data\EK\Desktop\Python  is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @TangerCity I believe you are having a space in the folder name, include the path inside double quotes, `os.system(f""" "{os.path.abspath('main.py')}" """)`

Comment: @TangerCity Apart form this, avoid using `os.system` inside the `mainloop` as it will freeze the GUI until the execution is complete (you may not notice in this case as the program finishes pretty quickly), use `subpocess.Popen` if you want to run the script separately.

Comment: That still gives the same output... If you could show me how it would work in a a correct answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My directory name contains spaces, most shells split up the arguments by assuming they are separated by spaces. So the solution is to place the part that contains the filename of the script between double quotes.

```
os.system('python "c:\data\EK\Desktop\Python Microsoft Visual Studio\MM\main.py"')
```

This worked!

Comment: In the comments I had told the same, you mentioned it did not work? Anyway, do consider using `subprocess.Popen` instead, if you don't want it to block the GUI's event loop.

Comment: If the two `.py` files are in the same directory, you can extract name of the folder from `__file__` and add it to `main.py` to determine a full path to it at runtime. The will allow you to avoid hardcoding the path into your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because os.system only accepts a command and not a filename.

You can replace this code

```
os.system("main.py")
```

Like this

```
os.system("python main.py")
```

Comment: I get this:
`Hello World`
`python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` So it seems that it gets printed again before I even click the `run the Code!` button